# Ionic SideMenu + MultiTabs + UiRouter

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I know there's a lot of question about things that don't work around here, for now I'd like to have others opinion about something that works but could definitely work better (or at least that's my hope).

I'm coding an app with ionic and I'm trying to leverage as much as I can from ui-router to optimise things. My transitions are super slow on android (did not try it on ios) and I reckon it could be due to lots of DOM being carried everywhere.

I have a stripped down working example of my app here:
http://jsbin.com/hogipo/1/edit?html,js,output

First: is that the correct way of doing things? How would you do it? What would you improve?

I tried to replace as much ion-view by ui-view as possible so I don't carry too much DOM/bindings and all.

I also tried to take app.sidemenu.item one level up (app.item) out of sidemenu but I lose track of the history by doing so, therefor no backbuttons between the list and the item anymore... I'm stuck having it as a subview. In my app the item is obviously more complex and things become slower and slower the more I add things there...

I guess I've been looking at this issue either for too long or the wrong way. Any help would be much appreciated!